# How to create colum with data in column but depends of the occurence of this data

Tags: python, pandas

So here is my data in pandas

```
      Movie        Tags
0  War film     tank;plane
1  Spy film     car;plane
2  Indie film   boat;plane
```

i would like to create new column with the tag column with 0 and 1  and add a prefix like 'T_' to the name of the columns.

Like :

```
      Movie        Tags     T_plane 
0  War film     tank;plane    1    
1  Spy film     car;plane     1 
2  Indie film   boat;plane    1
```

An the twist is that i would like to create the new T_ column only if there is more than 2 plane tag in the Tags column for example.

there is no duplicate tag in a row.

I have some ideas on how to do it like line by line with a split(";") and a df.loc[:,'T_plane'] for example.
But i think that may not be the optimal way to do it.

Regards

Comment: @jezrael how about the occurence of the data ? I see no condition in the answer ...

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Do you think occurence - count data or  occurennce set 1?

Comment: Ok i've edited the question with example data.

Comment: is possible duplicates in values like `tank;plane;plane` ?

Comment: no , no duplicate tags in a row.

Comment: @user462794 Use `df1 = df.Tags.str.get_dummies(';');df = pd.concat([df,df1.loc[:,df1.sum().gt(2)].add_prefix('T_')],axis=1)`

Comment: Use `df1 = df['Tags'].str.get_dummies(';')
df = df.join(df1.loc[:, df1.sum() > 2].add_prefix('T_'))`

Comment: @user462794 Please [`accept and upvote`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), `sum` values and filter, [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df['Tags'].str.get_dummies(';')
print (df1)
   boat  car  plane  tank
0     0    0      1     1
1     0    1      1     0
2     1    0      1     0

df = df.join(df1.loc[:, df1.sum() > 2].add_prefix('T_'))
print (df)
        Movie        Tags  T_plane
0    War film  tank;plane        1
1    Spy film   car;plane        1
2  Indie film  boat;plane        1
```